# Can someone create a "fake" JWT?

Tags: node.js, jwt

If I use JWTs to secure my http endpoints, is it possible for someone to create their own JWT using a valid payload but their own public/private key pair then send that to my server? How can I make sure that my server created the token?

Comment: it has to match the secret key and all the payloads

Comment: You keep your private key secret. That's it. You can verify that the cryptographic signature on the JWT was generated with your private key by using your public key.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts what if an attacker just creates their own token, completely independent of my server using a valid payload that can be read from a valid jwt. If they sent their token and public key to my server, it will validate because the token and public key match, correct?

Comment: Nobody's supposed to send a public key to your server... your resource server should only ever request public keys directly from your trusted authentication server(s).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Sorry I think I have a misunderstanding about how this works. I generate a random public/private key pair on the server when a user logs in. I create a token using the private key and a payload containing the user data using `crypto.createSign("RSA-SHA256")` in nodejs. I send the token + public key to the client, then when the client wants to access a protected endpoint, they send the public key + token to the server and it will validate. What am I doing incorrectly? If I need to store the public/private key on the server, then its not stateless?

Comment: "If I need to store the public/private key on the server, then its not stateless?" - That is correct.  JWT is not stateless.

Comment: There's also nothing wrong with using the same private key for all clients. There's no need to create a new private key for each user.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts If I use the same private key for every token, wouldn't it be possible for someone to take that single key and login as any account?

Comment: No, it would not be possible...

Comment: is it possible to generate token from one client machine and use this token to make request to server  from other client machine.